# Songs Package, Two song columns, left column 'glue' song to the bottom

Tags: songs

The last of three short songs, is glued to the bottom of the page.  \nextcol or \brk or \colbotglue seems to produce no effect.  I am looking to have all three short songs without leaving huge gaps in the left column, ideally with a blank space from the the third song to the bottom of the page.  I am also combining that with \section or \sbsection using the specific \songsection from songs package  I am using thhis with the memoir class.  I am not  not using any multicols environement at all.  What statement controls this behaviour?
[image: Song Latex spaces out songs]

```
\renewcommand{\colbotglue}{0pt plus .5\textheight minus 0pt}

\begin{intersong*}
    \songsection*{\color{darkbrown}Amen}
    Historically thiis traces back to ...
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Amen}
    \vskip 6pt
\end{intersong*}

% BEGIN Amen
\input{../Songs/Amen_v01}
\input{../Songs/Amen_v02}
\input{../Songs/Amen_v03}
%\vskip 5in
% END Amen
\nextcol*
\begin{intersong}
We would like to have a write up on the rightcolumn, so theleft column is ragged I have tried the renewcommand{colbotglue}{0pt plus .5 textheight minus 0pt}
\end{intersong}
\nextcol
```